# Ruby on Rails - Limit Database Query to One Result only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to query the database but only find out if there is at least one result or not. I am trying to minimize the cost for this transaction. What would the structure be in Rails to have the query be `SELECT TOP` or `SELECT FIRST` in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [exists?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F)

```
Person.exists?(5) # by primary key
Person.exists?(name: 'David')
Person.exists? # is there at least one row in the table?
Person.where(name: 'Spartacus', rating: 4).exists?
Person.active.exists? # if you have an "active" scope
```

Note that this limits the result set to 1 in the SQL query and the select clause is something like `SELECT 1 AS one`